# Apple Pay on Apple Online Store

Tags: apple-store, apple-pay

How can I use Apple Pay to purchase something online from the Apple Store? I have the normal purchase options with credit card etc. I assume that Apple must support their own payment system?
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apple does use its own payment system.

Using the Apple Store app, find the product you would like to purchase and add it to the shopping bag.

When done tap on the shopping bag tab at the bottom. You'll see a list of the products you have selected. Press the big black button named "Buy with (apple)Pay" (the button contains a graphical version of the Apple logo where I wrote (apple)).

Now you'll get a confirmation dialog and by confirming you can pay with Apple Pay.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean, as I have seen and used this on other sites (e.g. Kickstarter), but try as I might I couldn't find it anywhere on the website of the Apple Store iOS app. could this be region based? I'm from Australia, but Apple Pay is certainly supported here as I use it almost daily both online and physically.

Comment: Did you use the app like I wrote? Or did you go to a website? Please try the app.

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere on the website or the Apple Store iOS app

Comment: Can you do a screenshot of the iOS App from the exact place that I described in my answer? - Then I can advise further.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show better!

Comment: You need to press Check Out, and then take a new screenshot...

Comment: Added another screenshot from checkout, the redded out section is my bank details

Comment: Press payment and screenshot again...

Comment: Again, I've added more screenshots

Comment: I would call Apple to ask why your account does not have the Apple Pay option. Perhaps you didn't add Apple Pay to the Apple-ID you're logged in with.

Comment: I definitely have apple pay activated, I use it on my Mac, Watch and Phone both in physical stores and online (e.g. Kickstarter). I'll give em a call, thanks for your help.